# automatically create subfolder and save the file in sharepoint using powershell

Tags: powershell, file-upload

I am new in powershell, i want to save a file which powershell will automatically create new subfolder in sharepoint 2010 and save it ( the subfolder named should be todayname i.e. 25Oct2012) :

### here is the script :

```
$sharepointsave = "SiteURL+DocumentLibrarypath" + "/" + $today + "/"

New-Item $sharepointsave -type directory -Force

$sharepointpath = "SiteURL+DocumentLibrarypath" + "/" + $today + "/"
$sharepointsave = $sharepointpath + $filename + $today + ".xls"

$b.SaveAs($sharepointsave1)
```

however, it couldn't create the subfolder ...
would you please help

Thanks very much

Best Regards
Mary

Comment: Mary, can you please echo or Write-Host the $today variable, I think it contains some special characters which are invalid for a folder name!

Answer (score 1):

Mary,

I think the $today variable returns some special characters with it, which are invalid for a folder name and that causes it not to create the folder...

Can you please try date formatting like:

`$completeFolderName = Get-Date -format dMMMyyyy`

[Reference to Date Formats in Powershell](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692801.aspx)

UPDATE:
Here is how you create folders from PowerShell:

```
PS > $spFolder = $spDocumentLibrary.AddItem( 
>> "",[Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFileSystemObjectType]::Folder,"My New Folder" 
>>) 
PS > $spFolder.Update()
```

Please refer to: [Use PowerShell Cmdlets to Manage SharePoint Document Libraries](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2010/09/23/use-powershell-cmdlets-to-manage-sharepoint-document-libraries.aspx)

Comment: Hi, I have tried this, but it cannot create the subfolder in sharepoint (e.g. subfolder name'25Oct2012')

Comment: it said "Path not found" in sharepoint , so ...i guess it cannot create new subfolder...

Comment: Mary, I have updated the answer