# Authenticate from PowerShell and create a folder

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell, file-upload

I want a script that authenticates and then create a folder.

I am not performing the upload from my local machine.  It is happening from a continuous integration server so it needs to authenticate.

I see this question about PowerShell folder creation but how to authenticate?  [automatically create subfolder and save the file in sharepoint using powershell](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/49925/automatically-create-subfolder-and-save-the-file-in-sharepoint-using-powershell)

Comment: your environment? On-Prem or SPO?

Comment: This is for On-prem but I see the answer below for both

Comment: yes, i having scripts for both so just added them. Though it will helpful for others as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**For SPO**

```
$ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($siteUrl)
$ctx.Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($loginname, $pwd)
```

**For SP-OnPrem**

```
$ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($siteUrl)
$ctx.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($loginname, $pwd)
```

Make Sure you refer to the `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll` and `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll` before using above code.

Also passing the user name and password in plain file is not recommended but i had this sample as of now so posted. You can utilize powershell `Get-Credential` function to get the credentials at runtime.